# Time complexity of random algorithm

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, computer-science

I was wondering how to perform the complexity analysis of the following random algorithm. The answer are: $\Omega(n)$,  $O(n²)$, and  $\Theta(n)$.

At first I thought to perform the analysis by saying that *incremen*, *decrem*, and *MultiDecremen* are called $n/3$ each one, but the fact that $O(n²)$ and  $\Theta(n)$ got me confused.

```
public static int increm(int n){if(n==0) return 0; else return ++n;}
public static int decrem(int n){if(n==0) return 0; else return --n;}
public static int MultiDecrem(int n, int k){
    while(n != 0 && k !=0){
        n=decrem(n);
        k--;
    }
    return n;
}
public static void main (String...args){
    int n = args[0];
    final int seed = args.length > 1 ? Integer.parseInt(args[1]) : (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
    final Random random = new Random(seed);
    int compt=n;
    while(compt--!=0){
        int alea = random.nextInt(3);
        if(alea==0) n=increm(n);
        if(alea==1) n=decrem(n);
        if(alea==2) n=MultiDecrem(n,n/2);
    }
}
```

Comment: ncrem and decrem are constant time methods, while the complexity of MultiDecrem is linear. So the 'worst case' scenario in the main algorithm/function is that MultiDecrem is called within the while-loop, which results in a $n^2$ complexity. The best case is that only increm or decrem are called in that while-loop, which results in a linear complexity algorithm.

Comment: Thank you, but when I write $\Theta(n)$ is the average case so I do not care about the worst case $O(n^2)$?

Comment: In general it is harder to compute the average case complexity than the worst case. So yes, you could say not to care about the worst case, but just keep in mind that this quadratic complexity can in fact happen.

Comment: Based on the answer given below, you don't have to care about this quadratic complexity. Great :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously the time complexity is $\Omega(n)$, because the outer loop runs $n$ times.

Similarly, the time complexity is $O(n^2)$, because the complexity of `MultiDecrem` is $O(n)$.

Finally, consider that `MultiDecrem` was called $k$ times. Naturally, `decrem` helps us, so let's assume that the rest were `increm` calls and denote their number between $(i-1)$-th and $i$-th `MultiDecrem` as $a_i$. This gives a bound for the total number of operations that `MultiDecrem` preforms (modulo missing ceil and floor functions)

\begin{align}
(n+a_0)/2+((n+a_0)/2+a_1)/2 + \ldots \leq
n + a_0 + a_1 + a_2 + \ldots + a_k \leq 2n
\end{align}
because $\sum_i a_i \leq n$.
Hence, the algorithm is $O(n)$ and so $\Theta(n)$ as well.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Thank you very much. I see the main idea but I did not understand the part "denote their number between $(i−1)$-th and $i$-th MultiDecrem as $a_i$.

Comment: @Rafael In other words, the algorithm called in sequence $a_0$ `increm`s, then `MultiDecrem`, then $a_1$ `increm`s, then `MultiDecrem` again, and so on, until final, $k$-th `MultiDecrem` and last $a_k$ `increm`s.